# Determining, if a variable is a valid closure in PHP

Tags: php, reflection, closures

Using the following function:

`function is_closure($t) { return ( !is_string($t)  && is_callable($t)); }`

Can this return true for anything else, than an anonymous closure function? If so, what would be the correct way to determine, if a variable is a closure?

Many thanks

Comment: Objects are also callable if they implement [`__invoke`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The most deterministic way to check if a callback is an actual closure is:

```
function is_closure($t) {
    return $t instanceof \Closure;
}
```

All anonymous functions are represented as objects of the type `Closure` in PHP. (Which, coming back to above comment, happen to implement the `__invoke()` method.)

Comment: Something that tripped me up for a minute or two ... If your code is namespaced, make sure to escape \Closure to get back to global namespace.

Comment: You don't need to do `is_object($t)`, doing `instanceof` for a non-object will always return false.

Comment: On php 7.4 this does not work. print_r shows Object Closure but instanceof Closure returns false

Comment: @MarkusRenéEinicher I would guess your usage was within a namespace then. (Edited.)

Comment: @mario Ha! Of corse! Completly forgot about that. `instanceof \Closure` it is!

Answer (score 17):

I think you can use `instanceof Closure` though the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) states this should not be relied upon. I guess it works *for now*.

> Anonymous functions are currently implemented using the Closure class. This is an implementation detail and should not be relied upon.

**Update**
The Closure [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) has updated its guidance on this. It appears that this behaviour can now be relied upon.

> Anonymous functions, implemented in PHP 5.3, yield objects of this type. This fact used to be considered an implementation detail, but it can now be relied upon.

Comment: @mario beat me to it but I'll leave this here for the extra information (unless mario wants to merge this in with his answer)

Answer (score 4):

php.net suggests using reflections to figure out if the variable contains a valid closure or not

I use this little helper

```
function isClosure($suspected_closure) {
    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($suspected_closure);

    return (bool) $reflection->isClosure();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is supported with Reflection http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.isclosure.php

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error about that does not exist `ReflectionFunction`, use **backslash** before class:

```
// Closure
$closure = function () {}; 
$reflection = new \ReflectionFunction($closure);
// checkout if it is a closure
$test->isTrue($reflection->isClosure());
```